# Can't draw background on android TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add gridlines onto items inside a `LinearLayout` in a `RecyclerView` and have resorted to drawing them as a background on the TextViews in the `RelativeLayout`. However, the UI doesn't actually render with the background correctly drawn.

I can see on the design preview in AS, that what's going to be showing is indeed a cell with a gridline, but it doesn't actually render that way in the app. What am I doing wrong?

This is my layout row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/border"

          android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    style="@style/BodyText"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorData"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    style="@style/BodyText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my shape that I've defined as the background in an xml file called `border.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- View background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="@color/black" >
    </solid>

    <!-- View border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/black" >
    </stroke>

    <!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

This is the borderless layout. Just to see if it changes, I've defined my "border" to actually draw a completely black background, but it doesn't show up at all

[image]

in the design preview for the screen, I can see that it should be showing up.

[image]

Here is the `@style/BodyText` file

```
<style name="BodyText">
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you please put  android:color="@android:color/transparent" in solid element instead of black and text color property black

Comment: can you share `@style/BodyText` properties

Comment: @Rahul please see edit

Answer (score 0):

In your `border.xml` you have

```
<solid
    android:color="@color/black" >
</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/black" >
</stroke>
```

So, the background and lines colors are black. Also, the text is black by default.

Set background to transparent or any other colour.

```
    <solid
    android:color="#00FFFFFF" > // transparent
    </solid>
```

Comment: Yes, I want it to show up like that because right now it's not showing _any_ changes to the background

Answer (score 0):

I changed row layout little bit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorName"
    style="@style/BodyText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0.5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/temp1"
    android:text="Collector" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorData"
    style="@style/BodyText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0.5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/temp1"
    android:text="--" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use width of Textview as wrap_content or match_parent.
Don't use 0dp when using a background.

Answer (score 0):

Change solid color in border.xml according to your need.

I am used `#C8E7F5` this color

> ***border.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- View background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#C8E7F5" >
    </solid>

    <!-- View border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" >
    </stroke>

    <!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

I am making some changes in layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensorName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:text="Text1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensorData"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:text="Text2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:text="Text1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:text="Text2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:text="Text1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:text="Text2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output after above code is like below image:

[image]

I hope its work for you.